# SQL Server TSQL macro

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, macros, sql-server-2012

Via SQL Server 2012, I am doing a process repeatedly for multiple databases. I am creating a new view for each database based on the tables and views I already have in each corresponding database. The new views are in the same structure, and should be all put in a new database.

Background Info: Each database shares the same structure, same tables, same views, and same variable names for corresponding tables/views, except that the names of the databases and tables are different. And of course, the values of all the variables are different.

For example:

```
Database1:
View11:
ID(int), Age(int), Salary(float)

Database2:
View21:
ID(int), Age(int), Salary(float)

New View:
ID(int), Salary*0.1 as Revenue
```

My naive code:

```
USE Database3
GO
CREATE VIEW dbo.NewView11
AS
SELECT ID, Salary*0.1 AS Revenue
FROM Database1.dbo.View11

CREATE VIEW dbo.NewView21
AS
SELECT ID, Salary*0.1 AS Revenue
FROM Database2.dbo.View21
```

the NewView11, NewView21 are in the Database3.

I know it will be simple to copy and paste for multiple databases. But the actual number of the databases are more than 2 and the query is more complicated. So copy and paste may cause more careless errors more easily.

Can someone share some wisdom to do it with a more accurate and standard way, rather than my clumsy copy and paste way? I am open to any strategies to solve this problem. Here are some ideas I borrowed from other languages, it may NOT work here in SQL Server.

1. macro variable as one using in Excel.
2. a storage function as one using in Javascript/Python/Ruby, etc.
3. a loop.
4. Others.
   Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2201/making-a-more-reliable-and-flexible-spmsforeachdb/

Comment: This very much sounds like an [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)... Why don't you tell us why you'd want to achieve such a scenario?

Comment: Hi@mr.Reband, Thanks for the info. Looks good. I am digesting it slowly... Seems a lot of new info to me...

Comment: Hi@gvee, Thanks for the reminder. It could be. As I stated, I am looking for a solution to repeat the process multiple times more efficiently, rather than copy and paste the same code, and tweak them one by one. I am open to other strategies, if it is not a "Macro" way to deal with the problem.